# javax.websocket.DeploymentException: No decoder was found for message parameters present on the method [OnMessage], when trying to deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websocket, web-deployment

I have been working with Netbeans IDE to develop my website while also using Netbeans built in Glassfish/Tomcat servers with no issues; However when I try to upload my site to the hosting server, I am given an error while trying to deploy that I cannot find much information on, nor do I know why I am getting this error. I am using an AWS style hosting solution where I am installing and updating the files on the server myself, and not the hosting provider doing the work.  The error I get is this:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: No decoder was found for message parameters present on the method [onMessage] of class [WebsocketClass] that was annotated with OnMessage
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5160)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1386)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: No decoder was found for message parameters present on the method [onMessage] of class [WebsocketClass] that was annotated with OnMessage
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMethodMapping$MessageHandlerInfo.<init>(PojoMethodMapping.java:488)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMethodMapping.<init>(PojoMethodMapping.java:139)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:155)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:280)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:126)
    ... 38 more
```

As for onMessage, this is the method head,

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session,EndpointConfig config, String message, @PathParam("param") String name)
```

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Decoder.html

it says  `The lifecycle of the Decoder instance is governed by the container calls to the init(javax.websocket.EndpointConfig) and destroy() methods.` With this I assume that maybe the "EndpointConfig" call has something to do with this Decoder issues?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/EndpointConfig.html

I do have a few instances where I use a Base64 Decoder, but that is in another method which is called from within OnMessage, but I think that is something else separate from this.

I'm  just unsure why this issue only stems from the 1 host and not the others, nor do I know what do to about this issue.

Besides using the Built in Servers in Netbeans IDE, I also tried using another hosting solution I have that is already setup and this host is managed by the company itself, with Tomcat preinstalled and it uses C-Panel.  The deployment of the site to that Tomcat instance seemed to work, as I didn't get any errors in the Catalina.out file on that server when deploying.

I am wondering if anyone has any idea as to what could be causing this error?  I am assuming I might have messed up with something while installing Tomcat on the server, maybe the Server.xml file is the issue?  I just find it odd it has to do with WebSockets, if that were the case, though...  That's all I can think of between Netbeans build in servers and the managed hosting solution vs the solution I manage.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The server is complaining about the `EndpointConfig` parameter, which is not allowed. You can have:

- at most one parameter to receive the message content (cf. [OnMessage Javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/1.1/apidocs/javax/websocket/onmessage) for a list of types). There are some types supported by default, for the remaining you need a [`Decoder`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/1.1/apidocs/javax/websocket/decoder),
- multiple `@PathParam` annotated `String` parameters,
- an optional `Session` parameter.

An `EndpointConfig` parameter is allowed in the signature of a [`@OnOpen`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/1.1/apidocs/javax/websocket/onopen) annotated method, hence probably the confusion.

Comment: Hmm... Thank you for this.  I did read something similar to this mentioned before about what can be passed, but is there a reason why Netbeans servers don't complain about this, nor the other server, and why these servers can deploy?  The Socket and the endpointconfig work just find with the OnMessage in Netbeans, the data is passed with no errors, so I don't know why it would work fine in Netbeans if I cannot use EndpointConfig with OnMessage?  Are we sure it can't be something else?

Comment: I did want to add that I figured I would try out the EndpointConfig after posting this question and that is in fact the problem.  I did look at the Javadoc again which is  now where I see that info is from that I saw before, which is what you posted part of above.  It just is odd that I was able to do it with netbeans and that the other server deployed, without issue.  I would assume there is a reason for that?

Comment: I see no reason why Tomcat started by NetBeans should behave differently, unless you added a different implemenation of JSR 356 on the classpath.

Comment: I just clean/build and used that war file and then uploaded to both servers.  One server worked fine without changes, and the other worked after removing the EndpointConfig.  I find this very odd....  I don't think I really need The Endpoint Cnfig anymore though, as one of the things I was checking is if the message is being sent from the correct authenticated user, but OnOpen should be able to get that info, and I shouldn't need to check during each messsage because from waht I see a connection cannot be tampered with and only that user will be send messages?